# Page.OnAppearing() Firing Twice

Tags: forms, xamarin

When I push a new instance of my page onto the navigation stack, OnAppearing() fires twice and consequently two DeliveryNotePicker pages are created. There's nothing in the call stack that gives me any clues. Why might this be happening?

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ScannerMessages, Barcode>(this, "ScannerData", (sender, arg) =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { ItemScanned(arg.Value); });
    });
    try
    {
        if (picklist == null)
        {
            // Attempt to retrieve an existing picklist:
            picklist = (List<Pick>)Application.Current.Properties[PicklistProperty];
            branchName.Text = (string)Application.Current.Properties[BranchNameProperty];
            NextPick();
        }
    }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException)
    {
        // Create a new picklist:
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DeliveryNotePicker());
    }
}
```

Comment: OnAppearing should not be called twice. Could share the code where you page gets called and instantiated into the navigation stack?

Comment: `private void LvOnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs itemTappedEventArgs)
{
 Navigation.PushAsync(new BranchPicking.BranchPickingMain());
}`

Comment: And could you share the code that is calling the LvOnItemTapped? Also please share the rest of the code of BranchPickingMain(), I dont see why you have to use BranchPicking.BranchPickingMain() instead of just BranchPickingMain()

Comment: The above method is just the event handler for my ListView.ItemTapped. The namespace prefix I am using should not relate to the problem I am having in any way.

Comment: `public BranchPickingMain()
        {
            Title = "Branch Picking";
            BuildContent();
        }`

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on this line, does it get fired twice? private void LvOnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs itemTappedEventArgs) { Navigation.PushAsync(new BranchPicking.BranchPickingMain()); }

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: I would recommend stepping through each line on button click, and it will give you a clear picture, because from you are saying, I'm not sure why your OnAppearing is being called Twice. Alternatively, you could use something like this: if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(BranchPickingMain))
   return;
to prevent it from affecting you

Comment: Yes, I was considering using a similar hack to what you propose. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: The `OnAppearing ` should not been called twice .It should be code from somewhere else that affects here. I once encountered a similar scenario that was caused by the messageCenter. Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test with it? I'm not sure about the jump logic of your APP.

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered this bug, think it's caused when pushing a new modal within the OnAppearing function

Workaround is to either check the current page isn't the same as in Saamer's last comment or using a private counter to check number of opens